# Найти максимальное число k , для которого число n можно представить как сумму k различных натуральных слагаемых

Tags: java, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь вывести алгоритм для задачи разбиения натурального числа на максимальное кол-во различных слагаемых. Надо найти само k и вывести слагаемые.
Сам перелопатил кучу литературы по комбинаторике, дошёл только до такого:
n = 2+3+4+etc + (остаток до n, если число уже есть-убираем его из суммы и увеличиваем на единицу с конца число элементов=остатку.)
Т.е. если n=22, то
22 = 2+3+4+5+6+2 = 2+3+4+6+7

Совершенный затык в том, как его реализовать.
Пока делал что-то в таком духе:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    int[] s= new int[0];
    int i=0;
    int sum = 0;

  if(sum<x){
      sum+=i++;
      s[i]+=s[i++];
      System.out.println(s[i]);
    }else{
      s[i]+=s[i--];
      System.out.println(s[i]);
  }

}
```

Но это, очевидно, неверно.
Посоветуйсте, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать именно добавление единиц?

Comment: `n(n+1)/2` формулу используйте. Вам надо найти обратное. Думаю квадратное уравнение решить реально.

Comment: @pavel, прошу прощения, что обратное?
Типа, k(k+1)/2 = n, а отсюда найти k?
Это даст только количество, а не сами слагаемые.

Comment: ну окей. Сами слагаемые =`{1,2,3,4...,k-1, S - k(k-1)/2}`

Comment: @pavel, кажется, вкурил. Спасибо.

Comment: "...дошёл только до такого: n = 2+3+4+etc + ...". А почему с 2? Единица то чем провинилась?

Comment: *"Это даст только количество, а не сами слагаемые"* - а вы слагаемые в вопросе и не просите, заметим. Только число. Какой вопрос - такой и ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = 22;
    ArrayList<Object> s = new ArrayList<Object>();
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
       i++;
       if (i*2<n){
           s.add(i);
           System.out.println(i);
           n = n-i;
       }
       else{
           s.add(n);
           System.out.println(n);
           break;
       }
    }
```

выдает:

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
```

в последнее число запихивается весь остаток. задача выполняется меньшими усилиями

Comment: а ведь логично.
Кажется, я перемудрил.
Спасибо за ответ.